# Can I use heroku addons from India?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, chatbot

I am trying to create a bot and i have also deployed the node.js file to heroku .
I want mongodb add-on . Will I be able to use that from India because heroku regions cover only the following

```
eu         Europe                   Common Runtime

us         United States            Common Runtime

frankfurt  Frankfurt, Germany       Private Spaces

oregon     Oregon, United States    Private Spaces

sydney     Sydney, Australia        Private Spaces

tokyo      Tokyo, Japan             Private Spaces

virginia   Virginia, United States  Private Spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use it from India. You will not be able to deploy it to servers running in India (at the moment) but no problem to use Heroku from India.

If your target audience is in India then you should test the latency of US vs. EU deployment to see which one performs better from India.